# php preg_match use of dash

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a search form which has a preg_match to validate text, but my problem comes when I input something with a dash.

```
 if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z -]+$/", $_POST['inschrijvingnmr']) == 0){
```

The format that is allowed could be any of the following scenarios.

```
AAAAAA
aaaaaa
A-AAAAA
AA-AAAA
```

I am able to search using just the first two, but when I try to search for the 3rd and 4th type, I just get the "else" message saying to enter a valid search query.

Comment: All 3 of those input strings match: http://codepad.viper-7.com/J2rs4Q

Comment: Can you post a little more contextual code?  Note that testing `== 0` is unwise, since `FALSE` is returned on error whereas `0` is returned for no match. Test `=== 0` instead.

Comment: thanks. it turns out, which I hadn't thought of previously, that it is the == 0 that was causing the issue. I removed that and now the code works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Put the **hyphen** at the beginning of the group:

```
/^[-a-zA-Z ]+$/
```

It appears that you are checking whether the regular expression does *not* match ([`preg_match`](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns `0` if there are no matches).

Use `if (preg_match( ... ))` to check whether the regular expression matches, or `if (preg_match( ... ) === 0)` to check for a non-match.

Comment: It's valid at the end of the group because it can't be mistaken for a range